# Use Carthage with Swift 2.3

Tags: swift2, dependencies, carthage

I want to add this to my project:

[github "hyperoslo/ImagePicker"](https://github.com/hyperoslo/ImagePicker)

I am currently using swift 2.3, however when I build this using Carthage, it builds it in Swift 3, which obviously isn't compatible with my project.

Is there a way to use Carthage to build this dependency in Swift 2.3?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, but if you look in the build logs you will see an export:
`export TOOLCHAINS=com.apple.dt.toolchain.Swift_2_3`
If you execute the above in your terminal before calling `carthage` Swift 2.3 will be used.

Comment: do i just run the above in terminal before i build the cart file?

Comment: Yes, that is one way, and what I do at the moment.